# The TextBox is cleared if it has 8 characters xaml C#

Tags: c#, xaml, textbox

I want to make the textBox component clear after it has 4 elements (8 characters with spaces)

[Text box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmuWH.png)

Comment: What code is in question, I am not seeing any? Also I assume you're not using MVVM for binding, would be a great benefit to start using if not. Please update the post to include code that is not working so we can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Handle the textbox's `KeyDown` event and check `textBox.Text.Length == 8`. You can also force every other character to be a space.

*Untested* - might need to be tweaked depending on how the spaces fit into the 8 characters. If it's 4 characters with spaces between them that is only 7 characters.

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (textBox1.Text.Length == 8)
    {
        // do something with the text

        textBox1.Text = "";     // clear the textbox
    }
    // optional else if to only allow spaces for every other character
    else if (textBox1.Text.Length % 2 == 1  // odd index characters
        && e.KeyCode != Keys.Space)         // must be spaces
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```